# WP All Import: Feeds of Feeds

Tags: xml

I’m trying to import a knowledge base into a WP install using WP All Import (I have the pro edition). I’ve used the plugin many times before for ‘flat’ xml files where the info is all contained within the one file, it works great.

However, this knowledge base I am trying to work with has a top level xml file, which actually just contains the links to more xml files. Those xml files just contain links to more xml files, and so on, until you get down to the actual article/content.

I can’t quite get my head around how to get WP All Import to go to that top level xml file, create a page/post with the links on it at the top level, then follow the paths for all of the xml files that are linked to, so that it builds the knowledge base exactly as a mirror of the feed, with posts/pages of links continually drilling down until you get to the content.

The bottom level article can be at varying levels across the knowledge base, so some places it could be 3 levels down, others 6 or more.

So, in short, is there a way to get WP All Import to follow the trail of XML files to automatically recreate the knowledge base within WP using posts/pages/CPT ?

Comment: Sounds like a question for the WP All Import support channels. 3rd-party plugins and themes are actually off-topic here since it's rare that we can actually answer them - they require a lot of really specific knowledge about really specialized code